# What happen when call free on middle of struct's member in c?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I just wonder what's happen when free() called about member of struct tonight.
Let see below simple code in c.

```
typedef struct {
    int c[5];
    int a[10];
    int *b;
}stma;
int main() {
    stma *he = (stma*)malloc(sizeof(stma));
    int *ac = he->a;
    free(ac); //This point is crash.
    return 0;
}
```

The free make crash.
But next code is work well.

```
typedef struct {
    int c[5];
    int a[10];
    int *b;
}stma;
int main() {
    stma *he = (stma*)malloc(sizeof(stma));
    int *ac = he->c; //This point is changed.
    free(ac); //Work well.
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, I could think second will work well and first is not correct code too.

What I wonder is what is happen during first execution.  free() free 'a' variable, the middle of struct, not address of struct.

he->a is not malloced, dynamically assigned and couldn't be free.
In this case, he->c memory address is 00D2Ad50 and he->a is 00D2AD64.
The struct variable will be placed in heap by malloc().  he->c have same address of 'he'. And he->c + 4*5 is he->a.  he->a is also in heap?  Then, what happen on free(he->a)?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. The argument to `free()` has to be a pointer returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: That's undefined behavior.

Comment: *Why* would you want to do this, *even if* it was well defined?

Comment: What would _you_ expect to happen?

Comment: [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: It's very fast comments.   I intend  the first variable of struct will be same with address of struct.
@Barmar.  About your first comment, then, for example, it mean it have a list of address returned by malloc() and only a address in this list can be free() regardless of memory space?  I confused because not malloc() variable in struct is also in heap.

Comment: Yes, pointers to the middle are in the heap. But the memory management functions only know about the actual pointers that they returned. It might have a list of pointers, or it can put housekeeping information before that address. If you give it a different pointer, it won't be able to find the information about how to free it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first of your examples is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You try to free what you didn't get from a memory management function (`malloc`). And like undefined behavior means - it may crash, work or anything - the behavior is not specified by the standard. So anything may happen.

From §[7.22.3.3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2)¶2

> Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.<sup>1</sup>

Your second example is not undefined behavior and is perfectly legal - this is validated by the quote given below.
From §[6.7.2.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15)¶15 [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) N1570

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared.*A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. **There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.***

As there is no padding involved then the address of the first member is necessarily the one returned by the `malloc` previously called. By the quote previously mentioned about `free` this is alright.

Also another point to be made is - not casting the return value of `malloc` and checking the return value of `malloc`.

<sub>1. One violation of this would when you try to free memory from the middle of the allocated object or something you didn't allocate at all using memory management function.`int *a = malloc(sizeof*a * 5)` and then calling `free(&a[5])` this will be undefined behavior or even this `int a[10];` and then calling `free(&a[5])` would be one. For dynamic allocation, you can always shrink the allocated space using `realloc` (freeing the memory that is not needed.)</sub>